# Prevent computed with other computed as dependency from re-computing when actual value does not change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

I am trying to achieve something quite tricky regarding usage of multiple inter-dependent computed properties.

My initial question is the following :
We have a computed value A and a computed value B. B has A as a dependency. Now, the dependencies of A changes, but the output value is still the same, so it's recomputed but returns the same value.

From what I've found out on my investigation, even if the output value of A does not change, if A is re-computed, then B will abso be re-computed. I want to know if there is a way to achieve this behaviour

To provide you context, let me first give you a concrete example that's close enough to my real use case :

```js
<script setup>
  import { ref, reactive, computed } from 'vue';

  const formState = reactive({
    field1: '',
    field2: {
      field2Child: 'MyChildVal',
    },
  });

  const mapDependencies = (arrayDependencies) => {
    let dependencies = {};
    for (const { key, value } of arrayDependencies) dependencies[key] = value;
    return dependencies;
  };

  const resolveFromString = (path, obj, separator = '.') => {
    var properties = Array.isArray(path) ? path : path.split(separator);
    return properties.reduce((prev, curr) => prev && prev[curr], obj);
  };

  const listDependencies = ['field2.field2Child'];

  // Will re-render every time formState changes
  const dependencies = computed(() =>
    mapDependencies(
      listDependencies.map((key) => ({
        key,
        value: resolveFromString(key, Object.assign({}, formState)),
      }))
    )
  );
  
  const dependenciesAsString = (dependencies) => {
    return 'The dependencies are' + Object.entries(dependencies).map(([key, value]) => `${key} : ${value}`);
  }

  // Expected to re-render only when the output of "dependencies" changes. But on real usage
  const computedBasedOnDependencies = computed(() => dependenciesAsString(Object.assign({}, dependencies.value)));

  const ChangeState = () => formState.field1 = new Date().toString(); 
</script>
```

I created a live reproduction of this of stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-svtsu2?file=src/App.vue

The behaviour I expected from this : If the output of "dependencies" does not change, then the timestamp at the begining of "computedBasedOnDependencies" should not change

The behaviour I get : Even when "dependencies" output is not changing, when it's re-computed
"computedBasedOnDependencies" is recomputed as well

If you have any insight about something I don't understand correctly from Vue reactivity, or any other way to achieve this behaviour, I welcome any help whatsoever.

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 0):

Computed property functions are supposed to be pure functions, i.e. they don't make side effects, and function output depends only on input.

For any other logic, a watcher should be used. This is the case for a watcher, where can be throttled with either source function and/or a comparison of old and new value:

```
const computedBasedOnDependencies = ref(null);

watch(
  () => stringifyWithoutTimestamp(dependencies.value)),
  (val, oldVal) => {
    if (val !== oldVal)
      computedBasedOnDependencies.value = stringifyWithTimestamp(dependencies.value);
  },
  { immediate: true }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Even when "dependencies" output is not changing...

Well problem is **it is changing** - even if it returns the object with the same content as before, it is still a new object

```js
function getObject() {
  return { value: "A" }
}

const a = getObject()
const b = getObject()

console.log(a === b)
```

Vue does not do "deep" comparison as that would be a major performance hit (the value returned from `computed` can be anything - deeply nested object for example). SO if you need this, you must implement it yourself presumably using `watch` instead of `computed`

But before going that route you should be sure that what you are doing is not just a [premature optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)